# How do you pass local variables to views in Kemal?

Tags: html, crystal-lang, kemal

**Edit**: [Link for documentation](https://kemalcr.com/guide/#views-templates)

I'm new to Crystal and I'm trying to build a small web-app with Kemal framework.

I have some experience working with Ruby and it's frameworks (Rails and Sinatra).
In Rails/Sinatra you can pass local variables to views that you are about to render. Something like this:

```rb
render(:some_view, locals: { foo: :bar })
```

Variable `foo` with value `bar` will become available in view.

So I thought that the same goes here, but I can't find anything like that in [Kemal guide](https://kemalcr.com/guide/) or their [GitHub page](https://github.com/kemalcr/kemal) nor in their [Cookbook pages](https://kemalcr.com/cookbook/hello_world/).

What am I missing here?
Maybe there is some other completely different way of doing this in Kemal that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define variable in the controller

```
get "/" do
  name = "Sergey"
  render "src/views/main.ecr"
end
```

Use it in the view

```
<body>
  My name is <%= name %>
</body>
```